# AWS Lambda, Python serverless handler with url pattern / parameters

Tags: python, lambda, serverless

I am trying to set up a lambda function using Python and serverless. I was able to perform simple POST/GET requests and have them to proxy to my lambda function just fine.

Now I am struggling getting something like this to work with serverless:

```
GET /my_function/{foo}
```

In a way that I could get it by:

```
http://....aws.../my_function/bar
```

This is what I'm trying:

serverless.yml

```
functions:
  my_function:
    handler: handler.my_function
    events:
      - http: GET /my_function/{foo}
```

It deployed to aws, but I am not able to get the value. It says there is no key for the event:

handler.py:

```
def sitemap_entries(event, context):
  s = MyNiceClass(event['foo'])
  ...
```

What am I missing?

PS: It works on local invoke when I send `--data '{"foo": "bar"}'`

Thank you

Comment: Did the pointers in my answer help? Or are you still having issues accessing the path parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#lambda-proxy-integration) (which is the default setting so unless you've changed it you'll be using it) then the path parameters are inside `event` in an attribute called `pathParameters`, so to access them use:

```
event.get('pathParameters', {}).get('foo', None)
```